# Solution to transcendental equation with both Mathematica and Python

Tags: numpy, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I have the following issue with finding the roots of a non-linear equation. The equation is the following:

tanh[ 5* log [ (2/t)^(0.00990099) (1+x)^(0.990099) (1-x)^(-1) ]  ]-x = 0

Solving this with `NSolve`, for `{t, 0, 100}` returns the following with *Mathematica*:

[image: plot]

This what I was expecting by plotting the resulting roots versus the time parameter within this range. Now, I have tried to replicate this result with Python by using `scipy.optimize.root` but it seems that my code returns as a solution any value that I use as an initial condition, hence it is nothing else that the identity map. This can be also see in the pic below, where I used an initial condition `0.7`:

[image: plot1]

I have provided the code below:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import root

#Setting up the function
def delta(v,t):
    epsilon = 10**(-20)
    return np.tanh( 5*np.log( (2/(1.0*t+epsilon))**(0.00990099)*(1+v+epsilon)**(0.990099)*(1-v+epsilon)**(-1)))-v
#Setting up time paramerer
time = np.linspace(0, 101)
res = [root(delta, 0.7, args=(t, )).x[0] for t in time]
print res
plt.plot(time, res)
plt.savefig("plot.png")
```

I am not really sure if I am using the `scipy.optimize.root` correct, since the function looks ok as far as what I expect from its behaviour. Perhaps a mistake in the way I pass the `args`?

Comment: Setting `-0.08` instead of `0.7` for the initial solution guess of `root` works fine

Comment: @Stelios True, I just verified it. But when I changed it to `0.08` or `0.02` I lost convergence. Should it be that there exists a minimum interval for which the method converges? Also, Mathematica seems to behave well enough each time. What do you think?

Comment: scipy uses gradient based ("hill climbing") methods to find the root, whose success heavily depends on the initial guess. Mathematica's `NSolve` uses a more complicated algorithm, probably formulating the problem as the root of a polynomial (by first approximating the function by a polynomial). There is no initial guess involved in this approach, it only depends on how well the function can be approximated by a polynomial. Note that you can do the same in python as discussed [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/29290/21460).

Comment: @Stelios Thank you for coming back. The cited post is an interesting one. I tried to install the package to Anaconda at Win10 but it seems not possible to achieve, plus I could not find any guide to it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The root-finding methods that begin with a bracketing interval [a, b] (one where f(a) and f(b) have opposite signs) are generally more robust than the methods that begin with a single point x0 of departure. The reason is that the former have a definite field to work with, and can refine it iteratively. The [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) is a classical example of these, but it's slow. SciPy implements more sophisticated methods such as [brentq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html#scipy.optimize.brentq). It works fine here, with the bracket of [-0.1, 0.1] (which should be enough from looking from the Mathematica plot).

Also, t=0 is problematic in the equation, as it's not even defined then. Put a small positive number like 0.01 instead.

```
time = np.linspace(0.01, 101, 500)
res = [brentq(delta, -0.1, 0.1, args=(t, )) for t in time]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Indeed it looks as a safer options than the initial condition. Unfortunately when I apply the method in my case, I receive an error of the form: `f(a) and f(b) must have different signs` which I have no solution online. It is Python 2, Jupyter Lab on Anaconda Navigator. Any idea?